# Sum of series with triangular numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you please tell me the sum of the seires

$ \frac {1}{10} + \frac {3}{100} + \frac {6}{1000} + \frac {10}{10000} + \frac {15}{100000} + \cdots $

where the numerator is the series of triangular numbers?

Is there a simple way to find the sum?

Thank you.

Comment: Fixed $\LaTeX$ and problem statement.

Comment: @AhaanRungta you do not need to comment that here.

Answer (score 10):

$$S={1\over10}+{3\over100}+{6\over1000}+{10\over10000}+\cdots$$ $${S\over10}={1\over100}+{3\over1000}+{6\over10000}+\cdots$$ Subtracting, $${9S\over10}={1\over10}+{2\over100}+{3\over1000}+{4\over10000}+\cdots$$ Now do the same thing again, that is, divide by $10$ and subtract, to get $${81S\over100}={1\over10}+{1\over100}+{1\over1000}+\cdots={1\over9}$$

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Your manipulation is quite nice and makes the question too easy to solve.

Comment: Indeed, [WolframAlpha agrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28%28i*%28i%2B1%29%2F2%29%2F%2810%5Ei%29%29+from+i+%3D+1+to+infinity)

Answer (score 5):

Your expression is equal to $g(1/10)$, where 
$$g(x)=\frac{x}{2}\left((2)(1)+(3)(2)x+(4)(3)x^2+(5)(4)x^3+\cdots\right)$$

Take the power series $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and differentiate twice. We get $(2)(1)+(3)(2)x+(4)(3)x^2+\cdots$ if we do it term by term, and $\frac{2!}{(1-x)^3}$ if we do it the usual way. Thus 
$$g(x)=\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{2!}{(1-x)^3}$$
(when $|x|\lt 1$, and in particular at $x=1/10$).

**Remark:** The idea generalizes. The $n$-th triangular nunber is $\binom{n}{2}$. The same idea can be used to calculate $\sum \binom{n}{k}x^n$ for $|x|\lt 1$ and fixed positive integer $k$.

Comment: Good answer, but one mistake.  Differentiating $\frac1{1-x}$ twice gives you $\frac2{(1-x)^3}$ or $g(x)=\frac x{(1-x)^3}$.  Then plugging in $\frac1{10}$ matches Gerry's answer.

Comment: Thanks, fixed! I tend to forget about constants.

Comment: It was more than just the constant.  I think you only differentiated once.  The exponent is still wrong.

Comment: Thank you, exponent also fixed. Bad day!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might add another derivation *(devised by me)*. This one is long and involves dissecting the sequence into its simplest terms.

> $1/10 + 3/100 + 6/1000 + \ldots$
>
> $= 1/10 + (1+2)/100 + (1+2+3)/1000 + \ldots$ (from the definition of
>   triangular numbers.)
>
> $= 1/10 + 1/100 + 2/100 + 1/1000 + 2/1000 + 3/1000 + \ldots$
>
> (by grouping terms with similar numerator together)
>   $= (1/10 + 1/100 + 1/1000 + \ldots) + (2/100 + 2/1000 + \ldots) + (3/1000 +
>  \ldots) + \ldots$ $= 1/9 + 2/90 + 3/900 + \ldots$
>
> ($1/9$ is a common factor)
>
> $= 1/9 [ 1 + 2/10 + 3/100 + \ldots]$ $= 1/9 [ 1 + 1/10 + 1/10 + 1/100
>  + 1/100 + 1/100 + \ldots ]$
>
> (after rearranging the terms)
>
> $= 1/9 [ 1 + (1/10 + 1/100 + 1/100 + \ldots) + (1/10 + 1/100 + 1/100 +
>  \ldots) + (1/100 + \ldots) + \ldots ] $ $= 1/9 [ 1 + 1/9 + (1/9 + 1/90
>  + 1/900 + 1/900 + \ldots) ]$
>
> (the terms between the parentheses represent a geometric series
>   whose sum is  $10/81$)
>
> $= 1/9 [ 1 + 1/9 + 10/81 ]$ 
>   $= 1/9 \times 100/81$
>   $= 100/729$